# How to create excel complicated formula for multiple and/or criteria

Tags: excel, formula

I've scoured Excel forums and websites, but I haven't been able to find a formula that gives me the solution I'm looking for.

[image]

Let's say I want to count how many apples and/or seeds are at warehouses in California. I have two columns. I want to count all cells in column A that contain the words "apple" or "seed", but I need to avoid double-counting cells that contain both words (i.e. "apple seed"). Then, I want to cross-reference with column B, which shows which state the produce is in.

In the image I've linked, the correct count is 2: "apple seed" and "apple" are in California, but "orange seed" isn't. None of the formulas I've tried so far, though, are consistently giving me the right answer. The formula in the linked image, for instance, is returning the answer 3. What's the right formula for this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick answer, you can use this while figuring out a more elegant way.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(N2:N5;{"*apple*","*seed*"};O2:O5;"*California*")) - SUM(COUNTIFS(N2:N5;{"*apple seed*"}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that formula only works for this simple example. My actual document (with private information) involves many rows of data and more variables.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:
[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT(((COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A4)-1,0),"*apple*")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A4)-1,0),"*seed*"))>0)*(B1:B4="California"))`

**Edit for more criteria and header:**

`=SUMPRODUCT(((COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A2:A33)-1,0),"*apple*")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A2:A33)-1,0),"*seed*")+COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A2:A33)-1,0),"*turf*"))>0)*(B2:B33="B"))`

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is working just fine.
If you have a header, make sure you set the ranges properly as in the above. I get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This formula works in the example I've given, but when I transfer it into my actual sheet (which contains private information, which is why I can't share a screen grab here), I can't get it to work. Could it be because:

1) I'm adding more than two variables to count in column A, i.e. more +COUNTIF components to the formula; or 2) There are blank cells in column B in the real spreadsheet?

Comment: To be more clear, the formula returns a value in the real spreadsheet, but it isn't the right one.